# How to switch to dark theme?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, darkmode, android-dark-theme

I need to switch to a dark theme in the application, I do it like this:

```
private fun onOffDarkTheme() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            when (requireActivity().resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    prefs!!.edit().putBoolean(MODE_NIGHT, false).apply()
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                    startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity::class.java))
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                    prefs!!.edit().putBoolean(MODE_NIGHT, true).apply()
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                    startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
        } else {
            val uiModeManager: UiModeManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE) as UiModeManager
            when (requireActivity().resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    prefs!!.edit().putBoolean(MODE_NIGHT, false).apply()
                    uiModeManager.nightMode = UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO
                    startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity::class.java))
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                    prefs!!.edit().putBoolean(MODE_NIGHT, true).apply()
                    uiModeManager.nightMode = UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES
                    startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in Application, I check

```
 private fun isDarkThemeOn() {
        val uiModeManager: UiModeManager = this.getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE) as UiModeManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (prefs!!.getBoolean(Constants.MODE_NIGHT, false)) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
        } else {
            if (prefs!!.getBoolean(Constants.MODE_NIGHT, false)) {
                uiModeManager.nightMode = UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES
            } else {
                uiModeManager.nightMode = UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that resources (.mp4) are not pulled from the raw-night folder, they remain the same as they were, but if I switch through the settings, then everything works correctly. I understand that I'm confusing Dark Theme and Dark Mode, but I can't figure out how to fix it. My main theme, inherited from

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked with string resources, it's worked for me

[Implement dark theme](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#themes-styles)

[about setApplicationNightMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager#setApplicationNightMode(int))

```
private fun setAppNightMode(context: Context, isDarkMode: Boolean) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val uiModeManager = context.applicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE) as UiModeManager
        val mode = if (isDarkMode ) {
            UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        } else {
            UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        }
        uiModeManager.setApplicationNightMode(mode)
    } else {
        val mode = if (isDarkMode) {
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        }  else {
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        }
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode)
    }
}
```